# Attempting to implement a feature where a user can use their phone camera to take a picture and then it will be uploaded as their profile pic

Tags: android, firebase, android-camera, onactivityresult

I'm currently running into an issue with implementing a feature on my app where a user can take a picture using their phone's camera and then have it display as a bitmap image as well as be uploaded to Firebase.

I've seen several similar questions answered on here but nothing seems to be working for me, so I was hoping if someone could give my code a look and have insight for what I might be doing incorrectly.

My general process as of right now is that my "Choose from Gallery" option is working, but my "Take Photo" is not. When clicked in selectProfilePicOption(), I am able to take a picture and confirm it, but the data sent to onActivityResult() continues to get null. I want to be able to pass the taken photo and upload it as a Bitmap to my uploadImageToFirebase() function.

Thanks to all in advance for any assistance!

Here's my current code:

```
private void selectProfilePicOption(Context context){
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Choose your profile picture");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(options[which].equals("Take Photo")){
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST);

            }else if(options[which].equals("Choose from Gallery")){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select image..."), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }else if(options[which].equals("Cancel")){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    data.getExtras().get("data");
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    try{
                        System.out.println("attempting to store bitmap");
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                        uploadImageToFirebase(bitmap);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    filePath = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                        uploadImageToFirebase(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}



private void uploadImageToFirebase(final Bitmap bitmap){
    if(filePath != null){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child("images/ProfilePics/" + mUser.getUid());
        ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(SetProfileData.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SetProfileData.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int)progress + "%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reviewing this on taking/capturing photos: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.  The line `data.getExtras().get("data");` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The line `data.getExtras().get("data");` contains the thumbnail of your captured image, but for some reasons, you are completely ignoring it.

Do it this way,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data") //this line is important 
                      uploadImageToFirebase(bitmap);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    filePath = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                        uploadImageToFirebase(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

But beware the image thumbnail you received on `onActivityResult()` and uploaded to `FireBase` is not the full resolution image but just a compressed version of it. In order to get the full-size image, you can check out [this](https://medium.com/@rodrigolmti/android-get-camera-thumbnail-and-full-image-1bddfdc5347e)